# How to prevent Connection time out in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, timeout, connection

I am facing problem with connection time out,during jquery ajax operation. The problem scenario is that 
I am firing an ajax request which is taking too long to be served by the server(5 minutes) ..Since I know the fired request will take time to be served i have added a progress bar which will show the %age of work done..(Progress bar details are fetched by a different ajax request ,which is fired in every 1 sec)..

Now the problem is main ajax request to start the work is getting timeout in 20 sec .I dont want it to be time out because the response to this request will be a report which I want to display it to an user.
Even if the main request is getting time out progress bar still continues to fetch %age of task completed details and I can see the report getting build up in 5 minutes..

I am using ajaxform plugin by malsup to submit the ajax..request and options in ajax request are normal only..Is there any way to pervent this connection time out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your architecture.  Have your ajax request start a job, and then have it poll for progress.

Comment: But this problem I found only occurring in Firefox and that is also solved if I change the network setting to auto detect proxy..

Comment: You should never assume that a browser will allow you to keep a connection open indefinitely.